# N threads writing into M Files running in different priorites and keep a track of all files requested by and currently allocated to a thread

Tags: c, linux

I want to create a program, using POSIX threads, having `n` threads running at different priorities.

There are files (say `m` files) which are shared among these `n` threads. If one thread is using the file (assuming that it writing onto the file), no other thread will be allowed to use it. The code should maintain a Table that tells: which file it has acquired and for which file its requests are pending.

Also, we need a Monitor Thread to check for deadlocks ; any implementations hints/ideas?

Comment: What did you try so far?

Comment: How is a thread to look up the file it needs to access?  By name?  If a thread finds out a file is in-use, I assume that it should wait in a prioritised queue until the current user releases it, yes?

Comment: Does a thread ever need to lock more than one file at a time?

Comment: The requirement for a table such as you describe is a huge contraint that is likely to generate deadlocks if a thread can request access to more than one file to perform its operations.  No file should ever be locked up by a thread unless ALL the files it requires are available.  If the threads try to lock up files in some sort of loop, you will almost certainly generate deadlocks, so don't do it that way.

Answer (score 1):

You don't need to check for deadlocks. You have to write a nice code that makes it impossible to run into deadlock scenario. For that reason, I'd recommend you use try-lock approach to lock down a chain of files and unlock them back shall any of the lock acquisition fail.

Also, if you are using C buffered I/O, I'd recommend you stick with [`ftrylockfile` and `funlockfile`](http://www.kernel.org/doc/man-pages/online/pages/man3/flockfile.3.html) APIs. Otherwise use a synchronization mechanism that is most appropriate for your case, be that futex API or locks implemented using atomic instructions.

Comment: 'You don't need to check for deadlocks. You have to write a nice code that makes it impossible to run into deadlock scenario' - +1

Answer (score 1):

The standard unix way to accomplish this is: spooldirectories.

- file operations, such as rename / link / unlink are **atomic**
- have one central input spool-dir, where input files can be placed
- a process / thread that wants to process a file, starts by moving it to another name, or better: to another (work) directory (using the thread_id or process number as directory name is obvious.)
- (since this move is atomic there is no possible race condition!)
- after processing, the finished files can be moved to an output directory
- the *scoreboard* function is simply a readdir(+stat), maybe even inotify, on the work directories
- process starvation will always be a problem. Incompletely processed files will live forever in de workdirs. Having a stamp/ pid file in the workdirectories could help cleanup / restart.
- if designed well, this structure could work even after machine failure. The workers would have to maintain their own backup / log /stamp-file mechanism.
- if you haven't noticed yet: no locking will be needed.

Answer (score 0):

I hate C.  I have to try and think of a way to do this without classes:(

OK, a 'Sfile' struct to represent each file.  Has name, path, file fd/handle, everything to do with one file, plus an 'inUse' boolean.

A 'waitingThreads' array for those threads waiting for a set of files.

A 'Sfiles' struct with an array of *Sfile to hold all the files, a waitingThreads array and a lock, (mutex/futex/criticalSection).

Each thread should have an event/semaphore/something that it can wait on until its files all become available and some way to access to the set of files that it needs and somewhere to store the fds/handles/whatever for the files.

OK, off we go:

Any thread that wants files locks up the Sfiles and iterates the *Sfile array, checking if every file it needs is free to use.  If they all are, it sets the 'inUse' boolean, loads itself up with the fd/handles, unlocks and runs on - it has all its files.  If any file it needs is in use, it pushes itself onto the waitingThreads array and waits on its event/sema.

Whne a thread is done with its files, it locks the Sfiles and clears the 'inUse' boolean for the files it was using.  It then iterates the waitingThreads array - if the array is empty, it just unlocks and exits.  If the array is not empty, it tries to find threads that can now run with the files that are now free.  If it finds none, it just unlocks and returns.  If it does find one, it loads that thread up with the fd/handles, sets the inUse boolean and signals its event/sema - that thread will then run with its desired set of files.  The thread continues to iterate the waitingThreads array to the end, looking for mre threads that it can load up and signal with the remaining free files.  When it reaches the end of the array, it returns.

That, or something like it, will ensure that the threads always run with their complete set of files, prevent any deadlocks due to threads locking partial sets of files and does not require any polling.

If you really, really need that table thingy, you can build it inside the lock every time a thread enters or leaves the lock.  I would suggest mallocing a suitable struct, loading it up with all the details of the free files and waiting threads, and queueing it off to another thread.  You could just have some 'monitoring' thread that periodically locks up the Sfiles, dumps all the info and unlocks, but that keeps the Sfiles locked for the entire 'dump' time - you may not want that overhead - it's up to you.

Edit:

OH - forgot the priority thingy. The OS thread priority is probably useless for your purpose.  Have each thread expose a priority enum/int and keep the 'waitingThreads' array sorted by that priority, so giving the higher priority threads the first bite at whatever files are returned.

Is that good enough for your homework assignment?

Comment: Thanks I have been away, I will let you konow how it worked out :)